# Power a docking speaker directly from raspberry pi GPIO pins

Tags: rpi.gpio

I have a raspberry pi plugged into a small portable philips docking station and stream music to it (it's acting as a squeezebox player). At the moment I am running to power supplies, a 9V 2amp for the speakers and the standard 5v for the pi. 
I would like to combine the 2 to use only one power supply and I note the speakers can be powered from 4 AA batteries ie 6v.

Can I power the speakers directly off the power out GPIO pins even though the voltage is a bit low? Will this just give sub standard perform on the speaker or is it possible to actually cause issues on the pi as well?

Comment: You CANNOT power the speakers from GPIO pins! GPIO pins support only a few MILLIAMPERES. By all means please rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are powering the Pi via the microUSB socket the maximum current you can get into the Pi will be 2 amps (2 amp polyfuse).

So you could draw perhaps 1 amp from the expansion header 5V and ground pins.

Will your Pi power supply be powerful enough and will 5V and 1 amp be enough for your speakers?

There is one way to find out.

Comment: Thanks makes sense, shouldn't cause damage to RPI if the speakers are wanting to draw more though correct?

Comment: It may crash the Pi if starved of power.  That may cause SD card corruption if the card is being written as the Pi crashes.  I'd say unlikely.